# Exract the data based on a condition from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my table:

```
ProposalNo  itemtypenum Dummy
2015005005  427          1
2015006003  478          1
2015006003  2243         0
2015006003  2249         0
2015006004  470          1
2015006005  2247         0
2015006005  2298         0
2015006007  478          1
2015006008  471          1
2015006008  2245         0
```

I need the result as

```
ProposalNo  itemtypenum Dummy
2015005005  427         1
2015006003  478         1
2015006003  2243        0
2015006003  2249        0
2015006004  470         1
2015006007  478         1
2015006008  471         1
```

Enhanced the previous logic is, when there is a `ProposalNo` with `Dummy=1` and itemtypenum = 478 then only consider the rows with `Dummy = 0`, else ignore the rows from the table.

Comment: Your sample data and your rule do not seem consistent.

Comment: I got the data from the user, as per their request, 
Case i: first i need to check the proposalNo should not be null and  Dummy =1 , if i have the record then only i need to consider the records with Dummy=0 as one set for the Proposal number.
case ii: For these Proposal no: 2015006005 , dont have dummy=1 so i should not consider.

Comment: May we see the code you've tried, or did you just come to SO as a code-for-you service? And how does the `performance` tag apply to your statement? (You didn't include a question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do it (there are several):

```
SELECT t1.ProposalNo, t1.itemtypenum, t1.Dummy
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.ProposalNo IN (SELECT ProposalNo FROM table WHERE Dummy = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart.. Its Working :)

Comment: Enhanced the previous logic is, when there is a ProposalNo with Dummy=1 and itemtypenum = 478 then only consider the rows with Dummy = 0, else ignore the rows from the table.